# Muscular system in blender

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, add-on, shape-keys

I would like to know if there is a tool or an addon in Blender that can help me to create a muscular system, i.e. a way to move the mesh (like the contraction of biceps).

I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ki4IVZFzLuA) but I'm not sure how well it works.

Any advice or should i use shape keys?

Comment: There's brand new X-Muscle System for Blender. It supports jiggle, X-Mirror and it is dedicated to create whole Muscular Systems for characters. Check it out! https://blendermarket.com/products/x-muscle-system

Answer (score 3):

Do you need muscle jiggle? Thats the real question.

If yes you have to use softbody simulation. The Muscle Tools plugin is imho not very helpful, because it treats the muscles one by one and not like a whole muscular system. Here is how I would setup that:

[How do you assign multiple shrinkwrap modifiers to rig muscles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26415/how-do-you-assign-multiple-shrinkwrap-modifiers-to-rig-muscles/26419#26419).

If you don't need muscle jiggle than the simulation and shrinkwrap is just overcomplication and you can use bones and shapekeys to do everything. In that regard you can also use [stretch maps](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?345542-Addon-Tension-Map) and lattices for skin sliding.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Blender Muscle Tools](https://cgcookiemarkets.com/all-products/blender-muscle-tools/) can help, it's a commercial addon but at $20 doesn't seem to be overly expensive.

Comment: Already seen. Do you think a tool or addon could help (like this one)?
It isn't a problem of money. I have seen better results with shape keys than these tools but shepe keys it's sometimes complex and i don't wanna to waste much time on that

Comment: I can't really comment on that unfortunately, I am not much into animation myself, and I have never rigged or done any character animation since it's not my main work area. I just reaclled seeing that addon somewhere.Maybe someone else can answer that.